# Is there a way to interact with the Alt-Tab window with the mouse?

Tags: windows-7, alt-tab

I'm using Windows 7 with *ye good olde* Windows 2000 style (I favor usability and space over fancy-pants aero and effects) and am looking for a way I can make the ALT-TAB-Control interactable with my mouse.

I generally have many many windows open, and pressing tab or shift-tab over and over again begings to really frustrate me, if i want to reach a certain program.

Of course, I could just select the program on my taskbar, but that takes even longer.

I really like the way mac os x has its alt-tab menu - more or less exactly the same, but I can select the program with my mouse.

Is there something like that for my environment?

Comment: Have you tried [VistaSwitcher](http://www.ntwind.com/software/vistaswitcher)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and continue to hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, you can use the mouse to click the item you want.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Do I need to activate this?

Comment: This functionality was introduced in Windows Vista, but it seems the "old-style" Alt-Tab may not have it. In that case your best bet may be an alt-tab replacement...

Comment: I tried some replacements, but most of them rely on the "fancy" windows aero being activated, which I am absolutely not going to do.

Comment: If you don't want Aero, get Windows 8 :P